# What data-type does a TypeScript property need to be passed a function in a React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm creating a basic TypeScript React project to familiarise myself with React and TypeScript as I've never worked with either technology before.

Below is a basic component that I've put together as part of a course that I'm following along with, however the course isn't making use of TypeScript so I'm having to make adjustments as I go.

As I understand TypeScript, you have to explicitly state the data-type of each property that you are making use of within a component. Now I'm trying to introduce a 'click' property that I will pass a function to but I dont know which data-type is necessary.

```
import React, { MouseEventHandler } from 'react';

type PersonProps = {
    name: string,
    age: number,
    children: string,
    click?: 
  }
  
const Person = ({name, age, children, click}: PersonProps) => (
    <div>
        <p onClick={click}>I'm {name} and I'm {age} years old.</p>
        <p>{children}</p>
    </div>
);

export default Person;
```

Below is the code where I'm passing the function into the property field

```
const App = () => {
  const [personsState, setPersonsState] = useState({
        persons: [
          { name: 'Max', age: 16},
          { name: "Theo", age: 27},
          { name: "Tom", age: 63}
        ],
        otherState: 'some other value'
      });

  const [otherState, setotherState] = useState('Some other value');

  console.log(personsState, otherState);

  const switchNameHandler = () => {
      setPersonsState({
        persons: [
          { name: 'Jeff', age: 16},
          { name: "Bob", age: 27},
          { name: "Kyle", age: 90}
        ],
        otherState: personsState.otherState
      });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hi, I'm a React App</h1>
      <p>This is really working!</p>
      <button onClick={switchNameHandler}>Switch Name</button>
      <Person 
        name={personsState.persons[0].name} 
        age={personsState.persons[0].age}>My Hobbies: Racing</Person>
      <Person 
        name={personsState.persons[1].name} 
        age={personsState.persons[1].age} 
        click={switchNameHandler}>My Hobbies: Sleep</Person>
      <Person 
        name={personsState.persons[2].name} 
        age={personsState.persons[2].age}>My Hobbies: Design</Person>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I tried using `MouseEvent` as the data-type, but with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `click?: (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => void` as `onClick` will always return `MouseEvent`.

Plus as a bonus, to not write `children` every time with types and then get some errors because of wrong types, you can use `PropsWithChildren`

As you write Props type for every component in its file, you can name type just `Props` instead of `PersonProps`

Here is the final version.

```
import { PropsWithChildren, MouseEvent } from 'react'

type Props = PropsWithChildren<{
    name: string,
    age: number,
    click?: (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => void
}>
```

Comment: I assume that PropsWithChildren would then handle the type definitions automatically?

Also thank you for your answer it solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can add

```
type PersonProps = {
  name: string,
  age: number,
  children: string,
  click?: () => void, 
}
```

Although if you bind this click property to an onClick the default parameter of the function would be of type [SyntheticEvent](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html)

```
click?: (SyntheticEvent e) => void
```